# A normal proper model of an abelian variety with geometrically integral special fiber smooth at the reduction of the origin

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, neron-models

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Does there exist a proper flat morphism $X\to \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that the generic fiber is isomorphic to $A$, the special fiber is geometrically integral and smooth at the reduction of the origin, and $X$ is normal? This is true if $A$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Why is it true in the curve case?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/minimalmodel.pdf

Comment: One naive candidate for $X$ could be to take a projective embedding $A \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, take the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ and define $X$ to be the normalization of this closure. This $X$ will certainly be normal and proper, and I think it will also be flat.

Comment: @Jef the irreducible components of the special fiber probably can't be controlled this way

Comment: @crispr I think you are right. Your conditions certainly seem like a lot to ask for, but it might be possible.